# Why do I randomly see a significant difference in my RSI and that of Trading View

Tags: indicator

Now I realise my own RSI values will never be exactly the same as those from Trading View (TV), as I don’t have the same data for the first 14 periods. However I would expect the two to converge, and they do. Most of the time the values only differ by about 0.1. This leads me to believe that there’s no issue with my algorithm.

Unfortunately sometimes, and quite randomly, the two will vary by up to 5. It will last few minutes and then they match up again.

For reference, my interval is 1 minute, with the price at the end of every second being interpreted as the closing price for the current (minute) interval. I’m using Periods=14 and Exponential Moving Average with alpha = 1/Periods in my algorithm. I’ve verified that TV does the same. I’m obtaining price data via my exchange’s websocket.

Question: Under what conditions could there be such a random divergence in RSI if they’ve remained the same for a long time (more than 2 hours)? For example, could it be a case of TV and me receiving different price data and could this cause such a sudden significant difference?

Comment: IMH Opinion the most likely explanation is that occasionally you and TV receive different prices, as you mentioned. Perhaps because of an interruption in one of the two price feeds.

Comment: It would definitely help if you show some data. Best I can do now is guess.

Comment: @BobJansen I’m trying to gather data to compare though reproducing it and with 1 second data is near impossible. Guesses are absolutely fine